# Maze Program Can't Finish

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

So I'm writing a program that generates and then solves a maze. I have everything working except for this one little thing. The marker in the maze will get to the second to last step of completing the maze and then stop on and then move to a different direction. I've been working on this for about 2 hours now, tracing my code and can't seem to locate where or why it goes wacky at the last move.

The rules for the maze are that `X` are walls and CAN'T be moved through, `O` are possible areas that CAN be moved through, and the `.` is the starting point. The `-` are paths that I have already moved to. The marker can move in any ordinal or cardinal direction (North, Northeast, etc).

I have two matrices, one called `mat` which is displayed to the user with `X`'s and `O`'s and `-`'s. I also have another matrix called `visited` which is the same size as `mat` and is kind of the behind the scenes matrix which keeps track of what coordinates I can or can't move to. It stores `W` for walls, `Y` for coordinates I've already visited, and `N` for coordinates I can visit.

The way I solve the maze is by checking for possible moves starting from North and moving counterclockwise around the compass until I find a possible move. The marker cannot move to spot it has already moved.

If I come across a split path with more than one possible move, I place the coordinates of that position in two stacks called `splitx` for row and `splity` for column so I can come back to it later. If I hit a dead end where every square is either a wall or already visited, I backtrack to the last coordinates in my split path stacks, close off the path I just moved to, and pop the top values of the stack.

I also have another stack called `visitStack` which stores every move I make as `N` for North, `NE` for Northeast, on and on. This lets me retrace my moves and go to the last split path I encountered. Here is the code and below it, some chosen output. If you have any questions about the code or output or just clarification in general, ask away.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MazeLab
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter random starting seed  ===>>  ");
        int seed = input.nextInt();

        Maze maze = new Maze(seed);
        maze.displayMaze();
        maze.solveMaze();
    }
}

class Maze
{

    private char mat[][];               // 2d character array that stores the maze display
    private char visited[][];           // 2d character array that works behind to scenes to let me know where I can or can't move
    private Stack<String> visitStack;           // stack that stores every move I make as N, NE, E, SE, etc
    private int nowR, nowC;                     // coordinates for current position in the matrix
    private int startRow, startCol;             // coordinates for the starting position
    private boolean done = false;               // not that important
    private Stack<Integer> splitx = new Stack<Integer>(); // row coord for split paths
    private Stack<Integer> splity = new Stack<Integer>(); // col coord for split paths
    Random random = new Random();

    public Maze(int seed)
    // constructor which generates the random maze, random starting location
    // and initializes Maze class values.  If the random value equals 0 the maze
    // store an 'X' otherwise it store an 'O' in the maze.
    {
        Random randomize = new Random(seed);
        mat = new char[12][12];
        visited = new char[12][12];
        for (int r = 0; r < 12; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < 12; c++)
            {
                if (r == 0 || c == 0 || r == 11 || c == 11)
                    mat[r][c] = 'X';
                else
                {
                    int rndInt = randomize.nextInt(2);
                    if (rndInt == 0)
                        mat[r][c] = 'X';
                    else
                        mat[r][c] = 'O';
                }
            }
        mat[0][0] = 'O';
        startRow = randomize.nextInt(12);
        startCol = 11;
        nowR = startRow;
        nowC = startCol;
        mat[startRow][startCol] = '.';
        visitStack = new Stack<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
            for(int k = 0; k < mat[i].length; k++)
                if(mat[i][k] == 'X')
                    visited[i][k] = 'W';
                else
                    visited[i][k] = 'N';
//                                      Avoid going back to the starting point
        visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
    }


    void displayMaze()
    // displays the current maze configuration
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 12; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 12; c++)
                System.out.print(mat[r][c] + "  ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        if(done == false)
            pause();
    }


    public void solveMaze()
    {
    // for testing purposes, this is not the real method
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            getMove();
            displayMaze();
        }
    }

    private int numMoves()
    // This method determines if a position has a valid move or not       
    {
        int moves = 0;
        if(nowR != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC] == 'N')
            moves++;
        if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR-1][nowC+1] == 'N')
            moves++;
        if(nowC != 11 && visited[nowR][nowC+1] == 'N')
            moves++;
        if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC+1] == 'N')
            moves++;
        if(nowR != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC] == 'N')
            moves++;
        if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR+1][nowC-1] == 'N')
            moves++;
        if(nowC != 0 && visited[nowR][nowC-1] == 'N')
            moves++;
        if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC-1] == 'N')
            moves++;
        return moves;
    }

    private void getMove()
    {
        if(numMoves() > 1)
        {
//                                      checks for split paths
//                                      north
            if(nowR != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
//                                      northwest
            if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC-1] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
//                                      west
            if(nowC != 0 && visited[nowR][nowC-1] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
//                                      southwest
            if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR+1][nowC-1] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
//                                      south
            if(nowR != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
//                                      southeast
            if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC+1] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
//                                      east
            if(nowC != 11 && visited[nowR][nowC+1] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
//                                      northeast
            if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR-1][nowC+1] == 'N')
            {
                splitx.push(nowR);
                splity.push(nowC);
            }
        }
        if(numMoves() > 0)
        {
//                                      moves the marker, oriented to the right
//                                      north
            if(nowR != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC] == 'N')
            {
                nowR--;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("N");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON NORTH");
            }
//                                      northwest
            else if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC-1] == 'N')
            {
                nowR--;
                nowC--;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("NW");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON NORTHWEST");
            }   
//                                      west
            else if(nowC != 0 && visited[nowR][nowC-1] == 'N')
            {
                nowC--;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("W");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON WEST");
            }
//                                      southwest
            else if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR+1][nowC-1] == 'N')
            {
                nowR++;
                nowC--;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("SW");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON SOUTHWEST");
            }
//                                      south
            else if(nowR != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC] == 'N')
            {
                nowR++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("S");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON SOUTH");
            }
//                                      southeast
            else if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC+1] == 'N')
            {
                nowR++;
                nowC++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("SE");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON SOUTHEAST");
            }
//                                      east
            else if(nowC != 11 && visited[nowR][nowC+1] == 'N')
            {
                nowC++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("E");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON EAST");
            }
//                                      northeast
            else if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR-1][nowC+1] == 'N')
            {
                nowR--;
                nowC++;
                visited[nowR][nowC] = 'Y';
                visitStack.push("NE");
                mat[nowR][nowC] = '-';
//              System.out.println("PUSHING ON NORTHEAST");
            }
        }
        if(numMoves() == 0)
        {
            while(nowR != splitx.peek() && nowC != splity.peek())
            {
                switch(visitStack.pop())
                {
//                                  have to backtrack the opposite direction i previously went
                    case "N":   visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowR++;
                                break;
                    case "NE":  visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowR++;
                                nowC--;
                                break;
                    case "E":   visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowC--;
                                break;
                    case "SE":  visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowR--;
                                nowC--;
                                break;
                    case "S":   visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowR--;
                                break;
                    case "SW":  visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowR--;
                                nowC++;
                                break;
                    case "W":   visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowC++;
                                break;
                    case "NW":  visited[nowR][nowC] = 'N';
                                mat[nowR][nowC] = 'O';
                                nowR++;
                                nowC++;
                                break;
                    default: System.out.println("SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH BACKTRACKING");
                }
            }
//                                      blocks off dead ends
//                                      north
            if(nowR != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC] == 'N')
                visited[nowR-1][nowC] = 'Y';
//                                      northwest
            else if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR-1][nowC-1] == 'N')
                visited[nowR-1][nowC-1] = 'Y';  
//                                      west
            else if(nowC != 0 && visited[nowR][nowC-1] == 'N')
                visited[nowR][nowC-1] = 'Y';
//                                      southwest
            else if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 0 && visited[nowR+1][nowC-1] == 'N')
                visited[nowR+1][nowC-1] = 'Y';
//                                      south
            else if(nowR != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC] == 'N')
                visited[nowR+1][nowC] = 'Y';
//                                      southeast
            else if(nowR != 11 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR+1][nowC+1] == 'N')
                visited[nowR+1][nowC+1] = 'Y';
//                                      east
            else if(nowC != 11 && visited[nowR][nowC+1] == 'N')
                visited[nowR][nowC+1] = 'Y';
//                                      northeast
            else if(nowR != 0 && nowC != 11 && visited[nowR-1][nowC+1] == 'N')
                visited[nowR-1][nowC+1] = 'Y';

            splitx.pop();
            splity.pop();
        }
    }

    private void pause() 
    {   
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String dummy;
        System.out.print("\nPress <Enter> to continue  ===>>  ");                       
        dummy = input.nextLine();                               
    }
}
```

Here is the maze before the marker moves through it.
[image]

Here is the maze at the end. Notice how when the marker should move northwest to finish the maze, it stays in the same spot the next turn and then moves south the turn after that.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging it, stepping through the code to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes, I traced it several times over and don't understand why it doesn't move northwest at the last step. I tried placing a `System.out.println` statement for whenever the marker moves northwest and it printed when it was supposed to move at the last step, but the spot remained an 'O'

Comment: @Andreas http://i.imgur.com/4fkKYM7.png

Comment: @JonSnow, what did you do?

Comment: use enumerations instead of hardcoded strings, for detecting, N,S,W,E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you're in position (1,1) and find two moves: NW and S.

`if(numMoves() > 1)` fires and pushes *both* on the stack.

`if(numMoves() > 0)` fires and applies NW move, leaving you at (0,0).

`if(numMoves() == 0)` fires and starts backtracking because there are no moves from (0,0).

2 issues:

- Where is the code that detects that you found the exit?
- `if(numMoves() == 0)` is calling `numMoves()` using the *new* coordinates. Change it to `else`.

Comment: for trying to answer +1

Comment: Wow that makes me feel silly, all it required was a change in order of those `if` statements.

Comment: And I'm still working on the code for an exit condition/no solution, I just couldn't continue with this error lying around.